# Search in Input text And then search results will be dropdown list using Ajax PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**There Should be an Input textbox, If user writes any text it should display dropdown list of customer names**

```
<script>
    function custlist() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "custlist.php",
            success: function(result) {
                $("#customerlist").html(result);
            }        
        });
    }
    function showCustomers(str) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "customerlist.php",
            data:'q='+str,
            success: function(result) {
                $("#customerlist").html(result);   
            }        
        });
    }
</script>

<input type="text" oninput="showCustomers(this.value)" placeholder="Search here" name="CustomerNo" /> 
<select name="Cno" id="customerlist" onfocus="custlist()">
    <option value="">Customer Name</option>
</select>
```

custlist.php

```
<?php
    $sql2 = 'SELECT Customer_Name as Cname,No from customers order by Customer_Name';
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) { ?>
        <option value="">Customer Names</option>                
        <?php // output data of each row
            while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row2['No']; ?>"><?php echo $row2["Cname"]; ?>
                </option>
        <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

customerlist.php

```
<?php          
    $q = $_REQUEST["q"];
    // lookup all hints from array if $q is different from ""
    if ($q !== "") {
        $sql2 = "SELECT Customer_Name as Cname,No from customers where Customer_Name like '".$q."%s' order by Customer_Name";
        $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sql2);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0) { ?>
            <option value="">Customer Names</option>                
            <?php // output data of each row
                while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row2['No']; ?>"><?php echo $row2["Cname"]; ?>
                    </option>
            <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

I am getting the data in my dropdown, but I want that if I write something in text box then automatically it shows dropdown with matching that characters.

And one more issue I have...

2nd Issue:- When I type "abd" first it shows customer names starting with "abd" but automatically it shows next names starting with "ab" then "a" then empty..
Why is that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't need to open and close your PHP tags so much in your `.php` files. Just echo out the HTML instead

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 
Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "customerlist.php",
    data:'q='+str,
    success: function(result){
        $("#customerlist").html(result);
    }  
});
```

And php:

```
<?php

$q = $_REQUEST["q"];
```

Try doing this Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "customerlist.php",
    data: {q: str},
    success: function(result){
        $("#customerlist").html(result);
    } 
});
```

And php:

```
<?php

$q = $_POST['q'];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this but no luck First it gave correct result http://prntscr.com/dj9m8n then like this http://prntscr.com/dj9luj

Comment: And how can i merge textbox and dropdown?

Comment: In your customerlist.php you have the following line: <option value="<?php echo $row2['No']; ?>"><?php echo $row2["Cname"]; ?></option> I don't think this works because in an ajax call you need to echo json_encode() all the results and use them in jquery/javascript